# Using regular expression parsing address in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, regex, ssis, etl, script-component

We know that there is no out of feature for Regular expression in SSIS. We came to know that we need to write .Net script in custom Script transformation. However, we would like to write Java method for this, could any help us whether SSIS can support this if support how can I can call this method in SSIS.

Comment: If you can write a Java library or .dll , you should be able to import it into the c# script with the using statement like most other external librarys you can import into c# scripts.

Comment: @Prasad based on https://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2011/07/pattern-matching-in-ssis-using-regular-expressions-and-the-script-component/ this is not a limitation. A one liner to import RegEx `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` But using Java methods is a long and complicated unnecessary road to go in my view.

Answer (score 1):

Why using Java while there are easier solutions to implement??

### (1) Flat File Regex source

If you are looking to use Regular Expression on a Flat File Source, then you can benefit from the `Flat File Regular Expression Source` created by Microsoft community:

- [GitHub - SQL Server community samples](https://github.com/fan130/mssql-ssis-community-samples)

### (2) Regex within Scripts

Also if you are looking to implement regular expression inside Script Task or Script Component you can benefit from the `System.Text.RegularExpression` library which is apart from the .Net Framework. THere are plenty of tutorials found online:

- [Regex Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- [C# RegEx match examples](https://www.dotnetperls.com/regex)
- [Using Regular Expressions in C#](https://regexone.com/references/csharp)
- [C# - Regular Expressions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_regular_expressions.htm)

### (3) Regular expression transformation

Also there are some third part Regex transformation components:

- [Regular Expression Transformation](http://www.sqlis.com/post/Regular-Expression-Transformation.aspx)
- [RegexClean Transformation](http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/RegexClean-Transformation.aspx)

---

**Helpful articles**

- [DATA CLEANSING WITH REGULAR EXPRESSIONS IN SSIS](https://sqldusty.com/2011/11/06/data-cleansing-with-regular-expressions-in-ssis/)
- [SSIS: Transform data using Regex](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/531971/SSIS-Transform-data-using-Regex)
- [Pattern matching in SSIS using Regular Expressions and the Script component](https://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2011/07/pattern-matching-in-ssis-using-regular-expressions-and-the-script-component/)